# C# ZipArchive compression across entire archive instead of

Tags: c#, zip, compression

I created a ZipArchive and added a file to it and recorded the size of the ZipArchive.

I then added another file to the ZipArchive which was almost exactly the same in content to the first apart from a few bytes difference.

After this the size of the ZipArchive was essentially almost doubled.

It seems that the compression only applies within entries independently rather than across the whole archive.

I need a solution that does the latter. Is there a way to get it to do this?

Comment: You are looking for [solid compression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_compression). Unfortunately the zip compression doesn't support this, so you can't do it with ZipArchive.

Comment: As long as I can do it programmatically in C# that's fine. It doesn't have to be using ZipArchive specifically

Answer (score 0):

Use tar followed by compression instead. tar archives are a serialization of a directory structure of files with no compression. Compression is then applied to the entire archive, which allows the compressor to take advantage of similarities in adjacent files.

[SharpZipLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib/) provides what you need for this.